# Importing javafx files unrecognized

Tags: java, javafx, import

I have tried to watch several videos, downloaded and re-downloaded JDK etc.

I am currently using netbeans as IDE, and I want to import javafx, but I am unable to do so.

Any ideas on how it can be imported, in details? - So far no luck.

```
package ep.gui;

import javafx.application.Application;

public class EPGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: What build system do you use? Maven? Gradle? Ant?

Comment: I guess you're using Java 11? Or a JDK 8 version without packaged JavaFX?

Comment: Here you will find all the information you need: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: 1: Ant

2: Java SE 11 and Java SE 13 were the most recent downloads

3: Will try.